# How to add any rows by clicking html table in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wonder whether I can insert rows in html talbe by clicking them.

For example when I prepare this table like below, and by clicking them

```
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

My desired result is like this. 
And I would like to know how to add any rows by clicking

```
<table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
           <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        .
        .
        .
        .
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

If someone has opinion, please let me know.

Thanks

```css
table {
border-collapse:collapse;}

td {
border:solid black 1px;
transition-duration:0.5s;
padding: 5px}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You mean like clicking anywhere inside the table should keep appending the first row to the table?

Comment: what's the values of the row you want to insert ? is it duplicated from clicked row ? or any values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add table row in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery)

Comment: Did I answer your question below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("table").on( "click", "tr", function() {
       $("table").append($(this).clone());
   });
});
```

Note that it's necessary to pass the event from a parent element that's already there when the page is initially loaded - `table` - to all `tr`-elements using `on()`.
[jQuery on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to create new `tr` elements and add them to the table when it's clicked, you could simply create a `click` event handler to do so. For example:

```js
// Store DOM elements in some variables
const [tbodyEl] = document.querySelector('table').children;
const [trEl] = tbodyEl.children;

// Create an event handler function
const sppendAdditionalRowToTable = e => {
  const newTrEl = document.createElement('tr');


  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
    newTrEl.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
  }

  tbodyEl.appendChild(newTrEl);
};

// Call handler function on click event
tbodyEl.addEventListener('click', sppendAdditionalRowToTable);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: solid black 1px;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  padding: 5px
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#tableID').on( "click", "tr", function() {
    $("tbody").append("<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table id="tableID">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```